# android task killer app did not fully kill my application

Tags: android, taskkill

I have an application that I tried uses task killer app to forcefully close it. But when I open back the application, it remains back at the same activity before I task kill it. It did not return back to the main activity and go through onCreate again. The scenario that I hoped for is when the user kill the application, it will run onCreate again when the user open it but not stuck at the last activity that the user used before that. Any idea or comments what causes this? When I uses task killer app (Advance Task Killer) to close other application, it got no issue and close the entire application. But on this application, it's outcome a bit different than I anticipated.

Comment: FYI, Task Killers are not good for Android. Android is designed to handle resources very well. http://www.droid-life.com/2011/06/02/revisiting-android-task-killers-and-why-you-dont-need-one/

Comment: Yes I agree with you. But I can't prevent other users from not using it, so I'm trying to develop an application to respond the way I wanted it to do even if the user tried to task kill it.

Comment: Alright, the text was a bit hard to read. I couldn't make out if you were using it explicitly.

Comment: One question, will the application go through onDestroy when I task kill it with other app like advance task killer?

Comment: No idea, but I don't think so. I think there are using a SIGKILL, which is not following the normal route like onDestroy etc. Just a thaught. You can easily test this by adding LogCat loggings in the onDestroy.

Answer (score 0):

Android may manage resources well, but I do not need YouTube, Amazon App Store, GetJar, 1MobileMarket, Fruit Ninja & Mario Kart running all the time burning the battery. The AUTO Task Killers are not needed in the post Gingerbread Android, the MANUAL Task Killers however are still very much usefull. For example, my brother's tablet (Ice Cream Sandwich), he has been complaining about it not lasting long on a charge (He got it for Christmas). I installed ATK & it said there were 62 apps running. Some, like Lookout, EMail, even Facebook, I understand running in the background, so they are set to ignore by the Task Killer, but there are 8 Apps that are not ignored that restart for no understandable reason.